# gantt-task-react: Convert Date to specific format(DD/MM/YYYY) and return as Date Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date, data-conversion, gantt-chart

I am using [gantt-task-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gantt-task-react?activeTab=readme) with typescript, facing an issue while displaying the date in the required format(DD/MM/YYYY) I am able to convert the date using dayjs and other conversion methods, but all these returns as String format, but here used gantt chart needed type Date only. how can we achieve this

Conversion required for **start** and **end** fields in the below Task object.

```
let tasks: Task[] = [
    {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date(),
      name: 'Idea',
      id: 'Task 0',
      type:'task',
      progress: 45,
      isDisabled: true,
      styles: { progressColor: '#ffbb54', progressSelectedColor: '#ff9e0d' },
    },
    ...
];
```

Used below dayjs for conversion but returing string

```
export const formatDate = (date?: Date | string): string => {      
    return dayjs(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

Comment: A date value is in its core numeric, and formatted values are always text. So ..?

Comment: @Gustav
how can I achieve the required format of return as a Date type

Comment: You can't. A true date value carries no format. The format is applied for display only.